# Choosing color from a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcombobox

I'm looking for a way to store color skin options in a `JComboBox` and let the user select one and click apply. This will change the color of the running windows(JFrame). Is this possible? I only wan't like 2 or 3 color options. Should I co with another approach?

EDIT:

I've got a it to work but now im stuck in another dilemma. The objects in the `JComboBox` are namen `java.awt.color[something something]`, I wan't to turn it in to color names. Im passing a `Color Array` in to a `JComboBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think there is an solution here, except it is in a JList, but it should be a similar answer. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/jlist/

Comment: Great thanks! Just changed it from JList to JComobox, Sorry for a slow response!

Answer (score 3):

I think this
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ColorComboBoxComboBoxEditorDemo.htm